# nav_Msgs::GetPlan and make_plan service is not returning path

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have the move_base node running in my navigation stack. I call the GetPlan service separately to calculate the path (not Euclidean distance) between the robot start and a given goal points. However, instead of returning a path in the map, the service client returns a straight Euclidean distance across the obstacles in the map. What wrong am I doing?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337437/nav_msgs::getplan-and-make_plan-service-is-not-returning-path/) by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2019-11-12**:
What does your costmaps look like? Looks like there is only a static map layer.

**Comment by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on 2019-11-12**:
When I run rostopic echo for both the globalcostmap and the localcostmap, it shows proper values with 0s and some nos.. What else should I check?

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2019-11-13**:
You should be able to visualize them in rviz (by clicking [this](https://imgur.com/a/ImjC5gb) ). Do they look realistic in your case?

**Comment by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on 2019-11-13**:
Check this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/EGtTb6z). It looks fine but the path is generated across the obstacles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have wrongly set the static_map to false in the global_costmap_params.yaml file. I changed it true and now I get a proper path

---

Originally posted by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) with karma: 43 on 2019-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0